# Index and Variable errors

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm a noob to php/mysql programming and I had this form working but when I got a new computer it won't work. The HTML is a form that send the results to the php page which kicks it into a WAMP mysql database. Like I said, I had this all working beautifully and I got a new machine, reinstalled WAMP, copied over the database and info, and now it gives me nothing but notices and if I add die(mysql_error()) to the end ot the $sql - ("SELECT..... like it was before, it gives me a cannot connect error.

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");

if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("kalen_qc", $con);

$sql = ("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ' " . $root . " ' and `password` = ' " . $password . " ' limit 1");

//Retrieve data from the sql Query String
$cname = $_GET["cname"];
$job = $_GET["job"];
$apptype = $_GET["apptype"];
$priority = $_GET["priority"];
$daterec = $_GET["daterec"];
$datereq = $_GET["datereq"];
$po = $_GET["po"];
$authby = $_GET["authby"];
$phone = $_GET["phone"];
$fax = $_GET["fax"];
$motorplantnumber = $_GET["motorplantnumber"];
$quoted = $_GET["quoted"];
$incomphoto = $_GET["incomphoto"];
$repvalue = $_GET["repvalue"];
$eyebolt = $_GET["eyebolt"];
$motorassem = $_GET["motorassem"];
$conduitbox = $_GET["conduitbox"];
$conboxpos = $_GET["conboxpos"];
$coupler = $_GET["coupler"];
$couplexten = $_GET["couplexten"];
$couplrecess = $_GET["couplrecess"];
$couplflush = $_GET["couplflush"];
$motorweight = $_GET["motorweight"];
$motorfreq = $_GET["motorfreq"];
$application = $_GET["application"];
$appdesc = $_GET["appdesc"];
$specinstruc = $_GET["specinstruc"];
$reasonserv = $_GET["reasonserv"];
$obviousdamage = $_GET["obviousdamage"];
$cussupplyprod = $_GET["cussupplyprod"];

// Escape User Input to help prevent SQL Injection
$cname = mysql_real_escape_string($cname);
$job = mysql_real_escape_string($job);
$apptype = mysql_real_escape_string($apptype);
$priority = mysql_real_escape_string($priority);
$daterec = mysql_real_escape_string($daterec);
$datereq = mysql_real_escape_string($datereq);
$po = mysql_real_escape_string($po);
$authby = mysql_real_escape_string($authby);
$phone = mysql_real_escape_string($phone);
$fax = mysql_real_escape_string($fax);
$motorplantnumber = mysql_real_escape_string($motorplantnumber);
$incomphoto = mysql_real_escape_string($incomphoto);
$repvalue = mysql_real_escape_string($repvalue);
$motorassem = mysql_real_escape_string($motorassem);
$conduitbox = mysql_real_escape_string($conduitbox);
$conboxpos = mysql_real_escape_string($conboxpos);
$coupler = mysql_real_escape_string($coupler);
$couplexten = mysql_real_escape_string($couplexten);
$couplrecess = mysql_real_escape_string($couplrecess);
$couplflush = mysql_real_escape_string($couplflush);
$motorweight = mysql_real_escape_string($motorweight);
$motorfreq = mysql_real_escape_string($motorfreq);
$application = mysql_real_escape_string($application);
$appdesc = mysql_real_escape_string($appdesc);
$specinstruc = mysql_real_escape_string($specinstruc);
$reasonserv = mysql_real_escape_string($reasonserv);
$obviousdamage = mysql_real_escape_string($obviousdamage);
$cussupplyprod = mysql_real_escape_string($cussupplyprod);




$sql="INSERT INTO motor_checkin (cname, job, apptype, priority, daterec, datereq, po, authby, phone, fax, motorplantnumber, quoted, incomphoto, repvalue, eyebolt, motorassem,  conduitbox, conboxpos, coupler, couplexten, couplrecess, couplflush, motorweight, motorfreq, application, appdesc, specinstruc, reasonserv, obviousdamage, cussupplyprod)
VALUES
('$_GET[cname]','$_GET[job]','$_GET[apptype]','$_GET[priority]','$_GET[daterec]', '$_GET[datereq]','$_GET[po]','$_GET[authby]','$_GET[phone]','$_GET[fax]','$_GET[motorplantnumber]', '$_GET[quoted]','$_GET[incomphoto]','$_GET[repvalue]','$_GET[eyebolt]','$_GET[motorassem]','$_GET[conduitbox]','$_GET[conboxpos]','$_GET[coupler]','$_GET[couplexten]','$_GET[couplrecess]', '$_GET[couplflush]','$_GET[motorweight]','$_GET[motorfreq]','$_GET[application]','$_GET[appdesc]', '$_GET[specinstruc]','$_GET[reasonserv]','$_GET[obviousdamage]','$_GET[cussupplyprod]')";



if (!mysql_query($sql,$con));
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
header("Location: /");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Typetext/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Kalen Electric Repair Packet</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="qcstyle.css" />
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
<!-- This conditional is for IE8 and IE6 and earlier- 8 needs that display:table     -->
<!--[if !IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
    #wrap {display:table;height:100%}
</style>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showUser(str)
        {
            if (str=="")
                {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                    return;
                }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
            else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
                     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
            if 
                    (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
                }
                    xmlhttp.open("GET","insert.php?q="+str,true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
    function loadXMLDoc()
        {

        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">  <!-- This wrap div needs to encompass everything except the footer div at bottom -->

<div id="header">
        <div id="logo"> <!-- this extra div is just centering the fixed width area of the header content -->

            <a href="../index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Kalen Electric and Machinery Inc Quality Control" class="logo"/></a>


        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="main"> 

    <!-- Inside this main div we are floating the content to the left and the sidebar to the right  -->

        <div id="content">

            <h1>Motor Check&#45;In&#58;</h1>
            <form action="insert.php" method="post" id="horizontalForm">
                <div class="box">
                    <fieldset>
                        <label>
                            <span>Customer&#58;</span>
                         <select class="cname" name="cname"><option value="">Select One</option> <option value="GP Wauna">GP Wauna</option> <option value="GP Toledo">GP Toledo</option> <option value="GP Camas">Gp Camas</option></select>
                        </label>
                        <label>
                        <span>Job Number&#58;</span>
                            <input class="job" type="integer" name="job" onClick="this.value=''"/>
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">New Job</button>
                        </label>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <label>
                                <span>Apparatus Type&#58 </span>
                            <select class="apptype" name="apptype"> <option value="AC Motor">AC Motor</option> <option value="AC Motor 1ph">AC Motor 1ph</option> <option value="AC Motor/Gearhead">AC Motor/Gearhead</option> 
                                <option value="AC Welder">AC Welder</option> <option value="AC Submersible">AC Submersible</option> <option value="Stator Only">Stator Only</option> 
                                <option value="Service Call">Service Call</option> <option value="AC Generator">AC Generator</option></select>
                        </label>
                        <label>
                        <span>Priority&#58;</span>
                        <select class="priority" name="priority"> <option value="P1">P1</option> <option value="P2">P2</option> <option value="P3">P3</option></select>
                    </label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <label> 
                        <span>Date Received&#58;</span>
                        <input class="daterec" type="date" size="12" maxlength="10" name="daterec" onClick="this.value=''"/>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>Date Required&#58;</span>
                        <input class="datereq" type="date" size="12" maxlength="10" name="datereq" onClick="this.value=''"/>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>PO&#35;&#58;</span>
                        <input class="po" type="text" size="12" maxlength="20" name="po" onClick="this.value=''"/>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>Authorized By&#58;</span>
                        <input class="authby" type="text" size="12" maxlength="30" name="authby" onClick="this.value=''"/>
                    </label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <label>
                        <span>Phone&#35;&#58;</span>
                        <input class="phone" type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" name="phone" onClick="this.value=''"/>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>Fax&#35;&#58;</span>
                        <input class="fax" type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" name="fax" onClick="this.value=''"/>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>Motor Plant&#35;&#58;</span>
                        <input class="motorplantnumber" type="text" size="12" maxlength="20" name="motorplantnumber" onClick="this.value=''"/>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>Quoted&#58;</span>
                        <select class="quoted" name="quoted"> <option value="No">No</option> <option value="Yes">Yes</option></select>
                    </label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <label>                 
                        <span>Incoming Photo As Received&#58;</span>
                        <select class="incomphoto" name="incomphoto"> <option value="No">No</option> <option value="Yes">Yes</option></select>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>Replacement Value&#58;</span>
                        <input class="repvalue" type="text" size="12" maxlength="7" name="repvalue" onClick="this.value=''"/>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>Eye&#45;Bolt&#58</span>
                        <select class="eyebolt" name="eyebolt"> <option value="Good">Good</option> <option value="Bad">Bad</option> <option value="None">None</option></select>
                    </label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <label>
                        <span>Motor Assembly&#58;</span>
                        <select class="motorassem" name="motorassem"> <option value="F1">F1</option> <option value="F2">F2</option> <option value="Vertical">Vertical</option></select>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>Conduit Box&#58;</span>
                    <select class="conduitbox" name="conduitbox"> <option value="Full">Full</option> <option value="Half">Half</option> <option value="None">None</option></select>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>Conduit Box Position&#58;</span>
                        <select class="conboxpos" name="conboxpos"> <option value="3:00">3:00</option> <option value="6:00">6:00</option> <option value="9:00">9:00</option> <option value="12:00">12:00</option> </select>
                    </label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <label>     
                        <span>Coupler&#47;Pulley&#58;</span>
                        <select class="coupler" name="coupler"> <option value="Coupler">Coupler</option> <option value="Pulley">Pulley</option> <option value="None">None</option> </select>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>Extended&#58;</span>
                        <input class="couplexten" type="text" size="12" maxlength="10" name="couplexten" onClick="this.value=''"/>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>Recessed&#58;</span>
                        <input class="couplerecess" type="text" size="12" maxlength="10" name="couplrecess" onClick="this.value=''"/>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>Flush&#58;</span>
                        <input class="couplflush" type="text" size="12" maxlength="10" name="couplflush" onClick="this.value=''"/>
                    </label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <label>
                        <span>Motor Weight&#58;</span>
                        <input class="motorweight" type="text" size="12" maxlength="10" name="motorweight" onClick="this.value=''"/>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>Motor On Frequency Drive&#58;</span>
                        <select class="motorfreq" name="motorfreq"> <option value="Yes">Yes</option> <option value="No">No</option> </select>
                    </label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <label>
                        <span>Application&#58;</span>
                        <select class="application" name="application"> <option value="Direct Coupled">Direct Coupled</option> <option value="Belted">Belted</option> </select>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>Application Description&#58;</span>
                        <input class="appdesc" type="text" size="12" maxlength="100" name="appdesc" onClick="this.value=''"/>
                    </label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <label>
                        <span>Special Instructions&#58;</span>
                        <input class="specinstruc" type="text" size="12" maxlength="255" name="specinstruc" onClick="this.value=''"/>
                    </label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <label> 
                        <span>Reason For Service&#58;</span>
                        <input class="reasonserv" type="text" size="12" maxlength="255" name="reasonserv" onClick="this.value=''"/>
                    </label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <label>
                        <span>Obvious Damaged or Missing Parts&#58;</span>
                        <input class="obviousdamage" type="text" size="12" maxlength="255" name="obviousdamage" onClick="this.value=''"/>
                    </label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <label>
                        <span>Customer Supplied Product&#58;</span>
                        <input class="cussupplyprod" type="text" size="12" maxlength="255" name="cussupplyprod" onClick="this.value=''"/>
                    </label>
                </fieldset>
            <label>
            <input  type="submit" /><br />
            </label>
            </div>
        </form> 
    </div>
</div>
</div> <!-- close the wrap div here -->

<div id="footer">
    <div id="foot"> <!-- this extra div is just centering the fixed width area of the footer content -->
        <div id="left">
        <p>Kalen Electric and Machinery Inc.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <p>AC Induction - Version 1.0</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Errors it returns:

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: q in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 2
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: root in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 13
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: sprocket in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 13
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: cname in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 16
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: job in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 17
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: apptype in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 18
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: priority in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 19
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: daterec in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 20
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: datereq in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 21
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: po in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 22
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: authby in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 23
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: phone in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 24
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: fax in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 25
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: motorplantnumber in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 26
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: quoted in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 27
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: incomphoto in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 28
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: repvalue in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 29
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: eyebolt in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 30
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: motorassem in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 31
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: conduitbox in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 32
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: conboxpos in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 33
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: coupler in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 34
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: couplexten in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 35
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: couplrecess in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 36
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: couplflush in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 37
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: motorweight in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 38
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: motorfreq in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 39
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: application in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 40
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: appdesc in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 41
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: specinstruc in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 42
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: reasonserv in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 43
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: obviousdamage in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 44
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: cussupplyprod in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 45
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: cname in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 85
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: job in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 85
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: apptype in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 85
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: priority in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 85
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: daterec in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 85
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: datereq in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 86
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: po in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 86
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: authby in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 86
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: phone in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 86
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: fax in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 86
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: motorplantnumber in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 86
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: quoted in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 87
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: incomphoto in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 87
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: repvalue in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 87
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: eyebolt in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 87
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: motorassem in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 87
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: conduitbox in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 88
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: conboxpos in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 88
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: coupler in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 88
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: couplexten in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 88
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: couplrecess in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 88
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: couplflush in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 89
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: motorweight in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 89
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: motorfreq in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 89
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: application in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 89
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: appdesc in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 89
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: specinstruc in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 90
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: reasonserv in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 90
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: obviousdamage in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 90
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: cussupplyprod in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 90
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  744072  {main}( )   ..\insert.php:0
```

Comment: you're using Wamp? Did you reinstall Wamp on your new computer and set it up properly?

Comment: all the errors are already being listed. try eradicating them one by one

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable"  and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is in the notice itself.  The entry for `q` does not exist in your query string.

It's best to build error handling and input validation to ensure that the appropriate variable exists.

```
$q = (isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : null);
```

Since you are setting and referencing multiple variables, I would suggest you create a function that you can pass the corresponding variable.  This not only checks for existence of the corresponding variable, but it also escapes the variable for use in your query.

```
<?php 
function varExist($var){    
     return (isset($_GET[$var]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[$var]) : null);     
} 
$q = varExist('q'); 
...    
?>
```

Please note that per the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL
> extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and
> related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function
> include:
>
> ■mysqli_real_escape_string() ■PDO::quote()

There is additional documentation pertaining to the suggested alternative, [mysqli_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), that you may review.

Answer (score 2):

Basically all of your variables are empty.  Make sure to initialize them at the start of the code.  This way you won't get undefined index warnings.

```
$q = '';
$cname = '';
...etc
```

**Side Note**

This is really REALLY dangerous.  Never use $_Get when running sql.  The user can perform sql injection attacks that way.

```
INSERT ... Values ('$_GET[cname]','$_GET[job]'
```

Much Much Better

```
$cname = mysql_real_escape_string($cname);
$job = mysql_real_escape_string($job);
Insert ... Values (' . $cname . ', ' . $job . '
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't post the HTML Page to go with it.

Comment: While it's possible to initialize a variable before setting it to avoid empty or null values, I would suggest the route as posted in my solution.  Not only does this practice DRY, but it also makes the code a lot more readable and maintainable.

Comment: I would definitely have to agree with that @RobB.  Your solution was much more succinct and something that I will use in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Those are all notices, not errors. Most likely the new PHP installation has a stricter error reporting level and the previous computer just suppressed the same notices.

The notices themselves mean that the form has not yet been submitted or there's some other related problem why form data hasn't been sent.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables ("q", "root", "sprocket" etc..) should be coming from another page, hence the $_GET call. Have you tried running the form first? If you are simply loading this page on it's on, the variables will not be populated.

Answer (score 0):

In your case this might be the way to go: Set this in the very first line of your script:

```
// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

This will simply NOT GIVE OUT those "error" messages. This is not a good way to code, but in this case it's the best quick & dirty solution.

Comment: I agree that this will quickly remove the messages, but I find keeping error reporting on will help prevent you from making simple mistakes in code logic.

Comment: @JoshFrankel I totally agree with you, BUT he says he not a coder and just wants to get this thing running. So, it's okay, I think.